# разделение логов php по сайтам apache + php-pfm

Tags: apache, centos, php-fpm

Используется CentOS 7. Установлен апач 2.4.35 mpm event и php-fpm.
все php логи собираются в один файл ото всех сайтов.
я думал что опция

```
catch_workers_output = yes
```

поможет собирать логи индивидуально в логах апача, но это не помогло.
вся информация которую нагуглил не помогла сформировать логи индивидуально на сайт.
Я подозреваю что если создать индивидуальный пул для каждого сайта - это решит проблему, но опасаюсь, что это приведет к повышенному расходу памяти.

Какие варианты есть для записи php ошибок в индивидуальный файл на каждый virtual host?

файл php.conf сейчас такой:

```
 <Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">
 # we must declare a parameter in here (doesn't matter which) or it'll not register the proxy ahead of time
 ProxySet disablereuse=off
</Proxy>
# Redirect to the proxy
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
</FilesMatch>

#
# Allow php to handle Multiviews
#
AddType text/html .php
#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

ProxyErrorOverride on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в файле /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf ищем такую строку:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

и комментируем ее:

```
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

когда php-fpm не находит лог файла - он отправляет вывод ошибок назад в апач  и там собираются ошибки php.

```
;catch_workers_output = yes
```

**catch_workers_output** трогать не надо - оставим его закомментированным.

За два дня непрерывного гугления на английском и русском такого ответа мне найти не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Можно запустить отдельный php-fpm для каждого сайта на отдельном сокете и у каждого указать свой лог:

```
[site1]
catch_workers_output = yes
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/site1.sock
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0660
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php/site1.error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

[site2]
catch_workers_output = yes
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/site2.sock
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0660
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php/site2.error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

А в виртуалхосте апача уже указать для каждого сайта свой сокет. В этом случае логи php-fpm будут писаться в разные файлы. Ну и, соответственно, придется настройки php прописывать для каждого сайта. С другой стороны можно получить гибкие независимые настройки php-fpm

Comment: Это значит что для каждого сайта будет свой пул? Правильно я понимаю? Такой вариант приведет к дополнительным расходам памяти, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: да. На каждый будет запущено своё кол-во ожидающих воркеров

Comment: не хотелось бы этого. так как сайтов штук 20 и перешел на php-fpm именно из за того чтобы экономить память. 
Других вариантов кроме как создать свой пул для каждого сайта - нет?